# L2 regularization of XGBoost in tidy models

Tags: tidymodels

I'm using tidymodels packages to use XGBoost model.

my models is

```
boost_tree(mtry = tune(), trees = 1000, learn_rate = tune()) 
%>% set_engine('xgboost', objective = 'binary:hinge' )
%>% set_mode('classification')
```

And I wonder where to put L2 regularization hyperparameter lambda.

R xgboost document lists lambda term,

but there is no lambda term in tidymodels boost_tree document.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any engine specific parameters inside the `set_engine()`, for example `%>% set_engine('xgboost', objective = 'binary:hinge', lambda = 2)`.